# WordPress: вложенные группы полей или другое решение для сортировки

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть группа полей, внутри которой, скажем, 10 пар полей. Каждая пара - поле для изображения и поле для текста. Нужна возможность сортировать эти пары между собой, либо выставлением номеров, либо перетаскиванием мышкой, т.е. по аналогии с тем, как сортируются сами группы полей. См.скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли в этом месте научить Wordpress менять пары местами?

Comment: Какой плагин-то? Чем реализованы группы?

Comment: Плагин Advanced Custom Fields. То, что на скрине, это просто 4 поля внутри созданной в нем группы.

Comment: Используйте ACF Pro. Там есть repeater.

Comment: Я вот думаю, может это как-то вкладками сделать. Пары полей там можно объединять во вкладки. Проблема в том, что вкладки тоже не имеют функционала сортировки. Интересно, можно ли их как-то без огромных трудозатрат дописать, чтобы они это начали уметь? Программировать умею, но в WP пока нуб.

Comment: ACF Pro уже смотрю, спасибо!